# Si j'écris « Je te propose d'envoyer un mail » : qui réalise l'action, moi ou mon correspondant ?

Tags: usage, sujet

Tout est dans le titre. Lorsque j'écris à un collègue « Je te propose d'envoyer un mail », je sollicite de sa part qu'il le fasse (et non moi). Si j'avais pris le parti de porter l'action en propre, j'aurai plutôt écrit « Je me propose d'envoyer un mail ».

Autant dans la proposition « je me propose » semble être interprétée clairement par les gens, autant « je te propose » semble ambiguë pour beaucoup.

J'ai donc deux questions :
Du point de vue du langage théorique, J'ai juste ou faux ?
Du point de vue pratique, constatez vous aussi beaucoup d'ambiguïtés sur une telle formulation ?

Answer (score 5):

D'un point de vue « théorique » le sujet du verbe *envoyer* n'est pas spécifié.

Voici deux phrases dans lesquelles le sujet implicite est clairement différent:

> Je lui propose de lire ce livre puisqu'il en a l'occasion.
>   Je lui propose de lui lire ce livre.

Dans la seconde phrase, la présence du pronom *lui* permet de désambiguïser, mais ce n'est pas toujours possible.

Quant à savoir qui est supposé faire l'action dans la phrase « Je te propose d'envoyer un mail »… sans autre indice, je pense qu'il vaut mieux n'écarter aucune des hypothèses *moi*, *toi* ou *nous*.

Answer (score 4):

Techniquement parlant, la phrase « Je te propose d'envoyer un mail » signifie que c'est vous qui faites la proposition mais rien ne dit qui fait l'action d'envoyer le mail. C'est donc grammaticalement ambigu. Pour lever cette ambigüité, il faudrait écrire « Je te propose que j'envoie un mail », mais c'est un peu lourdingue.

Cela étant dit, en pratique, je n'ai jamais constaté que ce genre de phrase était mal compris.

Answer (score 2):

Dans "je me propose" : c'est le verbe "se proposer", équivalent de "se désigner pour faire une action". Pas d’ambiguïté sur qui fait quoi.

Dans "je te propose" l’ambiguïté demeure quant à savoir qui fait quoi.
L'interlocuteur peut parfaitement comprendre que le "je te propose" équivaut à "je te demande ton avis sur cette action". Tout dépend du contexte des discussions préalables et pour ne pas avoir de doute il aurait mieux valu écrire, "je te demande" ou "je t'invite à "...

Answer (score 1):

Intuitivement c'est l'autre personne qui envoie le mail, pas toi.

Answer (score 1):

Formellement, comme l'indiquent les autres réponses, on ne peut exclure aucune possibilité. D'ailleurs, c'est toi qui fais l'action de proposer.

Maintenant, en pratique, si cette phrase m'est adressée, je la comprendrai toujours comme que c'est à moi d'écrire ce mail ; et l'emploie **pour dire à mes interlocuteurs de le faire**. Comme tu dis, si j'avais voulu dire *moi*, je l'aurais dit différement. À la rigueur, dans certains contextes, ça désignera *nous*, mais là encore je dirais plutôt « je te propose qu'on envoie ce mail », sauf à parler très formellement de nous à l'impersonnel.

Par contre, si je ne **veux pas comprendre** que tu me dis de le faire, alors cette phrase est l'occasion rêvée pour ça :·) C'est plutôt comme ça que je le prendrais.